# Update/insert table with wrong column name - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have a table with 5 columns and sometimes I update or insert new entries inside that table. I get the key/values from a json service, but this service added one more field and now when I try to update or insert new entries inside the table I get the error:

> Values not inserted. Error: no such column: email

I get that error from this line:

```
sqlite3_prepare(_database, queryChar, -1, &statement, NULL);

if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE)
    NSLog(@"Values not inserted. Error: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
```

*queryChar* has this format:

> UPDATE contents SET [id] = ?,[phone] = ?,[name] = ?,[websiteurl] = ?,[postalcode]
>   = ?,[email] = ?,[url] = ? WHERE id = 69

I wonder which is the most effective approach to solve this kind of error. Should I check every column name if it exist in the table and then add it to the queryChar ?

Comment: you table parameter please?

Answer (score 0):

For creating your table you need to create it like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MYTABLENAME(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,id TEXT,TABLECOLUMN1 TEXT, TABLECOLUMN2 TEXT, TABLECOLUMN3 TEXT);
```

Also you have to change your database for adding new column in your database

[**its mandatory to alter your table to add new column added later in your existing table**]

```
-(void)ChangeDB:(NSInteger)newDbVersion
{
    switch (newDbVersion)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            "ALTER TABLE MYTABLENAME ADD COLUMN NEWCOLUMNTOBEADD TEXT"
          //run this query in your sqlite 
        }
        break;
  default:
            break;
    }

}
```

**Here is your update query now after fetch data from json where NEWCOLUMNTOBEADD is new data added in your database table at runtime**

```
update MYTABLENAME  set TABLECOLUMN1 ='%@', TABLECOLUMN2='%@', TABLECOLUMN3='%@',  NEWCOLUMNTOBEADD = '%@' where id ='%@'
```

More about [ALTER command](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_alter_command.htm)